# Is it possible to remotely debug a single and specific WAR deployment on Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, remote-debugging, jpda

I have access to a remote Tomcat server with a number of different deployed WARs. I can't thoroughly test the WARs locally because of some remote system dependencies and therefore would like to remotely debug them. Because this is a production Tomcat server and I don't have access to setup additional remote servers (e.g. for stage testing), I would like to reduce as much as possible the security and performance issues of remote debugging via the Java Platform Debugger Architecture. My understanding of using JPDA with Tomcat is that it reveals all deployed WARs for debugging. Because most of the WARs are in production use, my scenario requires only debugging new deployments. Is it possible to exclusively limit which deployments should be accessible?

Obviously, short and sweet answers are acceptable (yes/no). I haven't found any documentation to say otherwise, so I assume it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Possible or not I think you should not debug in a production environment since IT IS A PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT.

The recommendation is to check the log files generated by the application so you can see the behavior (if it raise an exceptions in a class/process/method or if everything is just working as expected).

Looking at google I found this: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing#Q2

Did you tried what it is stated in the link above?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. But that doesn't provide a solution to my question because it again enables debugging across the whole Tomcat server (i.e. http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing#Q1)

Comment: Also, I agree that I *shouldn't* be debugging on Production and I do refer to log files, but for some circumstances, it would be more efficient to step through the code remotely instead of deploying our rather large WAR package every time changes are made. And as I mentioned, testing locally is not possible.

Comment: Yes, Eclipse can debug remote apps: http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html